# MacOS Mavericks: wget getting stuck with local ip but not with localhost

Tags: macos, networking, wget, localhost

I am facing a weird problem on my Macbook (Mavericks).

I'm serving some files over http.

When I try to get the files using wget:

- it works perfectly using localhost or 127.0.0.1
- it starts but get stuck when using my local ip

See illustration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN5Pu.png).
The first download from 'localhost' happens smoothly, the second from my local ip, starts but get stuck around 11% and seems to stall forever.

I tried serving the files using different techniques:

- with MAMP
- using node.js
- ...

I always get this problem, irrelevant of the file being served or the server technique/port.

I'm no network expert but this is quite strange to me...

When I try different files, it the download always gets stuck around 66kbytes...

Any idea why this might happen ?

Comment: I tried serving the files with npm http-server as well and get the same problem